# How can i write these items for constructor in a for-loop?

Tags: android, listview, for-loop, dynamic, adapter

so I'm currently writing an app for android, and im still a noob in java/android.
Anyways i have this 2 strings, one with names and the other with emails, and i want to output them in a listview with a custom adapter. 
It works fine so far but i dont know how to set the items dynamically (with a for loop).
To create the adapter and so on, I used this tutorial: 
http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

I simply changed the ImageView to a second TextView.

In the tutorials code there are 5 items added to the list, but i need them dynamically, since Im not always having the same amount of name+emails to output

I already tried putting it in a for-loop by doing:

```
Weather weather_data[] = new Weather[names.length];
for(int z=0; z == names.length){
    Weather[z]={new Weather(names[z], emails[z])};
}
```

I also tried it with adding "new" infront and trying to set everything null before, basically trial&error  since i dont know much about it.

So can anyone tell me how I add the items dynamically? 
(Ps: sorry if I used wrong names to describe anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
Weather weather_data[] = new Weather[names.length];

for(int z=0; z < names.length; z++){
    weather_data[z] = new Weather(names[z], emails[z]);
}
```

Give this a read to learn how for loops work
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

and this one for arrays
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: thank you very much, this worked for me. (I could I already tried that... guess I'm wrong)
Also thanks for the links.

Comment: @Verel please read about upvotes/accepting answers, and how SO works in general.  Also welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ArrayList<Weather> weatherData = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i < names.length(); i++){
    weatherData.add(new Weather(names[i], emails[i]));
}
```

Then when you need it as a `Weather[]` use `weatherData.toArray()`

Comment: Hey I tried your solution and android studio told me to cast weatherData.toArray() to Weather, and then I got a force close. 
But thanks for your help. :)